# Set Session mode inside Stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: t-sql, plsql, triggers, teradata

While running this procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DISABLE_TRIGGER(
in p_database varchar(50), in p_trigger_name varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE L_SQL VARCHAR(1000);    


set l_sql='alter trigger ' ||p_database|| '.' ||p_trigger_name|| ' DISABLED';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL;   

commit;    END;
```

I'm getting this error:

> SPL1027:E(L30), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(5510):Invalid session mode for procedure execution.'.

[Executed: 1/3/2016 3:50:30 PM] [Execution: 0ms]

Can anyone tell me how to set the session mode inside procedure?

Comment: This is a helpful resource on this topic.  http://www.nazmulhuda.info/5510-invalid-session-mode-for-procedure-execution

Answer (score 0):

> 5510 Invalid session mode for procedure execution.
>
> Explanation: The
> session mode within which the CALL SQL is submitted is different than
> the one in which the stored procedure was created. A stored procedure
> created in ANSI mode cannot be executed in Teradata mode and vice
> versa.

You can't set the session mode within a procedure, this is set at logon and can't be modifed within a session.

If you actually need to run this SP in both Teradata & ANSI mode you must create two versions, one within each session mode.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this issue when I created the stored procedure using Teradata Studio client and called first time using DBeaver sql client. I resolved this error by creating/replacing the stored proc and then calling it 1st time from the same sql client DBeaver.

Comment: This is due to the stupid`TMODE=ANSI` default connection setting in Studio. Either switch to `TMODE=DEFAULT` or simply delete it.